# What is the best way to secure a wpf client app calling web api services

Tags: wpf, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying to determine a good strategy for authentication between a single WPF application of which calls to Web API services.

The client WPF app should be the only application to ever call the Web API.
I think I do have some unique requirements I must abide by. For example, The boss does not want to use ssl in any way; he is paranoid of users may having to deal with certificates.

Like I said, the client application is the only client using the Web API. The API just calls a list of stored procedures on a separate server.

Currently, we have a user membership database that does not align with any membership db standard, but we currently have over 200,000 members. One of the stored procedures currently authenticates the user with the membership db. The client application requires valid users to sign in to the application at start-up, however, we are wanting to secure all of the Web API requests sent from client to prevent non-valid requests being made to the server and so to prevent.

We are concerned about using the individual accounts or local authentication to essentially authenticate every web API request because of the added cost.

I have been thinking that what we are really needed to do is pretty much authenticate that it is our software client(WPF application) making the request and this authentication could open up all the controllers and actions for requests made by the client rather than the user. The user and its authentication is somewhat separate and is in place to prevent unauthorized users on a particular machines install of the application.
So you must have a valid user account to use the application.

Any suggestion would be great. I am just asking to get pointed in the right direction. I am really new to security so all suggestion will be valuable to me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're really new to security I would *strongly* advise against doing anything that isn't 'vanilla'. I'm pretty sure the easiest way to achieve what you're describing is ASP.Net Identity: http://www.asp.net/identity , but that's going to collapse if your boss insists on SSL paranoia. Identity, as applied to Web API and WPF, provides the client with a bearer token that persists for a duration set by you. That bearer token is attached to every call to the API from the client, so every call is authorized individually.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer @goobering . After a lot of research I have decided on a HMAC related version of security of which I modified a bit to accommodate our unique model. Your right, with ssl being not a option is really limited my possibilities.